# what is the error here when i enter the integers in udp code Clint in server side returns this error?

Tags: java, server, udp

> Equation Received:- 4*4
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For > > > input string: "4*4"
>   at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>   at Calc_Server_UDP.main(Calc_Server_UDP.java:47)

Comment: `4*4` is not a number

Comment: i know because i use // Use StringTokenizer to break the 
   // equation into operand and operation 
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inp); 
  
   int oprnd1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
   String operation = st.nextToken(); 
   int oprnd2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

Answer (score 1):

It means that the code is trying to turn a `String` value into an `int` (using `Integer.parseInt`), but the value it encountered is `"4*4"` and that is not parseable as an integer. (`parseInt` expects simple numbers like `44`. It isn't clever enough to do things like evaluate expressions).

Comment: these my code i face the issue // Use StringTokenizer to break the 
   // equation into operand and operation 
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(inp); 
  
   int oprnd1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
   String operation = st.nextToken(); 
   int oprnd2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());